# MariaDB: Are foreign keys and indexes enabled after restart?

Tags: database, mariadb

I've disabled foreign key checks and indexes while I am bulk inserting millions of records (to speed up the inserts).

Do I have to enable indexes and foreign keys manually or can I just restart the MariaDB instance?

Comment: How did you disable it?

Comment: ALTER TABLE [table] ENABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE [table] ALTER INDEX [index] IGNORED

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ALTER TABLE always changes the table definition permanently, neither a rollback or a restart of the server will change the table definition.

To enable the index again just execute ALTER TABLE with option `INDEX NOT IGNORED`.